# Is it safe to pass an untrusted format string to string.Format?

Tags: .net, string-formatting

- Are there security implications for passing a user-provided (untrusted) format string to [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)?
- Can this lead to unexpected code execution? Can it result in infinite CPU or memory consumption?

Please assume that the following are untrusted inputs:

- Format string
- All arguments (assume them to be primitive types like integers, strings, datetimes. Certainly no user-provided types.)
- The culture

Exceptions being thrown are not a problem because that is easily handled.

Comment: It would definitely give rise to the possibility of an exception, but I don't think you can break into the computer or get access to data not specifically given to the format string this way so you should be safe in that regard. So it depends on whether you think an exception would constitute a security problem. You could potentially take down a web application if you stuffed such a string in the right place.

Comment: Are you in control of the `CultureInfo` that is used for formatting, along with the parameters? Do you care about exceptions being thrown?

Comment: as long as you aren't using it for code, i'd say its pretty safe.

Comment: I don't know of any problem or scenario with string.Format where you can get it to eat memory unbounded. Obviously, if you give the string.Format method a value that is a huge string, a format like `"{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}......{0}"` would of course build a really large string, which might be a problem.

Comment: It is never safe since you don't know if it matches the argument list. For example: `string.Format("{0}")` is the simplest format string that will fail.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That alone doesn't say much. Not matching the argument list simply throws a `FormatExcpetion`. I wouldn't consider that unsafe behaviour.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: but OP asks (in the title) if it _"is safe to pass an untrusted format string to string.Format"_. I would say no since a runtime exception is not safe code. **Edit** Ok, now OP has edited his question (_"Exceptions being thrown are not a problem"_).

Comment: @EMCOR it also depends on what you are doing with the string when you are done with it. Are you feeding this string in to a SQL query non parameterized? that could easily cause unexpected code execution.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain In this question I'm only concerned with the formatting operation. Assume that the result of that Format is simply discarded.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to produce very long outputs with rather small format strings. This can cause performance problems and potentially even out of memory errors.

For example `string.Format("{0,9999999}",0)` produces a string that consumes 20MB of RAM. You can repeat that pattern to increase the output size further.